# RCurl custom header with hyphen

Tags: r, rest, rcurl

Hi I want to send a custom header using `R's RCurl` package.

It provides a function `getUrl():`

```
getURL("http://example.com", httpheader = c(Accept = "application/json", X-My-Token = 666), verbose = TRUE)
```

The REST API expects **X-My-Token** but I can only send **XMyToken**
When I use the hyphenated token I get the following error:

```
Error: Unexpected '='
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is fairly simple: just use a String like

```
"X-my-token" = 666
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this question and answer out there. I ran into this myself :-)